# How to add libraries to index.html by yarn

Tags: frontend, node-modules, yarnpkg

My question is about architecture and how to add installed libraries to index.html?
I'm working with SAP application (AngularJS, nodeJS). All worked fine, but when I migrated from bower to yarn i got stuck.
I don’t understand how to add libraries to index.html.

Later I had the following file structure:

```
.
├── bower_components
|   ├── …
|   └── …
├── node_modules
|   ├── …
|   └── …
├── app
|   ├── …
|   └── …
├── bower.json
├── package.json
├── index.html
```

And earlier I automatically added js files into script section by wiredep 
Index.html:

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/tether/dist/js/tether.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-read-more/dist/readmore.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/js-xlsx/dist/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-js-xlsx/angular-js-xlsx.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-ymaps/angular-ymaps.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/query-string/query-string.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-oauth2/dist/angular-oauth2.js"></script>
```

But later when I migrated from bower to yarn I have only one node_modules folder:

```
.
├── node_modules
|   ├── … modules to backend (nodejs)
|   └── … modles to frontend (angularJS and so on)
├── app
|   ├── …
|   └── …
├── package.json
├── index.html
```

When I use gulp-inject to automatically add js libraries in my index.html, gulp adds all js files (more then 1000 files) to index.html. Most of them related to backend.
How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to use bundles. require all libraries in main bundle file like this: `'use strict';
var angular = require('angular');
var moment = require('moment');`

browserify can help with that.

Hope this puts you on the right track.